# ¿Como agregar una clase a un elemento html y luego en la misma o en otra función quitársela?(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, css3, css-transform, selectores-css

**Los pongo en contexto:**
Hice un slider de imágenes en la que cambio el background image al hacer click al boton de izquierda o derecha de mi slider, pero, quiero agregar un efecto de fade hacia la izquierda si presiono el botón derecho y un efecto de de fade a la derecha si presiono el botón izquierdo. Funciona bien la primera vez(Lo intente añadiendole clases css donde ya estaban el codigo para las animaciones), pero la segunda vez  que uso cualquiera de los botones, ya no se dan las animaciones.

Les paso mi código ```javascript

````
  var flechaIz = document.getElementById('flechaIz');
  var flechaDe = document.getElementById('flechaDe');

  //seleccion del boxSlice  
  var boxSlice = document.getElementById('boxSlice');

 //seleccion de fotos 
 var milanes = ['./images/milan.jpg', './images/milan2.jpg', 
 './images/catania2.jpg'];

 //Creacion del evento que dispara las funciones
 flechaDe.addEventListener('click', sliceIz);
 flechaIz.addEventListener('click', sliceDe);

//funciones principales  
var contador = 0;

function condicionesCon(){
if(contador == -1){
    contador = 2;
}
else if(contador == 3){
    contador = 0;  

}

  if(boxSlice.classList.value == 'fadeInLeft'){
    boxSlice.classList.remove('fadeInLeft');
}
if(boxSlice.classList.value == 'fadeInRight'){
    boxSlice.classList.remove('fadeInRight');
}
}

function sliceIz(){
boxSlice.style.backgroundImage = `url(${milanes[contador]})`;
boxSlice.classList.add('fadeInRight');
contador = contador - 1;
condicionesCon()
}

function sliceDe(){
boxSlice.style.backgroundImage = `url(${milanes[contador]})`;
boxSlice.classList.add('fadeInLeft');
contador = contador + 1;
condicionesCon()
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Encontré la solución:** Primero, le agregue al boxSlice una clase llamada "none"(esto fuera de cualquier función), al ejecutar la función principal use "boxSlice.replace" para reemplazar "None"  por "fadeInLeft" o "fadeInRight" luego utlice un setTimeout para luego enviar la ejecucion a una funcion externa que remplaza "fadeInLeft" o "fadeInRight" por "none".

Les dejo el código:

```
boxSlice.classList.add('none');
var milanes = ['./images/milan.jpg', './images/milan2.jpg', './images/milan3.jpg', './images/milan4.jpg', './images/milan5.jpg'];

flechaDe.addEventListener('click', sliceIz);
flechaIz.addEventListener('click', sliceDe);

var contador = 0;
function condicionesCon(){

if(contador == -1){
    contador = 4;
}
else if(contador == 5){
    contador = 0;

}
}
 function sliceIz(){
boxSlice.style.backgroundImage = `url(${milanes[contador]})`;
boxSlice.classList.replace('none','fadeInRight' );
contador = contador - 1;
condicionesCon();
setTimeout(fadeImages, 300);
}

function sliceDe(){
boxSlice.style.backgroundImage = `url(${milanes[contador]})`;
boxSlice.classList.replace('none', 'fadeInLeft');
contador = contador + 1;
condicionesCon();
setTimeout(fadeImages, 300);
}
function fadeImages(){
if (boxSlice.classList.value == 'boxSlice fadeInLeft'){
    boxSlice.classList.replace('fadeInLeft', 'none');

}
if (boxSlice.classList.value == 'boxSlice fadeInRight'){
    boxSlice.classList.replace('fadeInRight', 'none');
 }

}
```